GStreamer pipeline writing UDP stream frames to JPEG images, but some frames are missing
I have written a C++ code using a GStreamer pipeline that takes a UDP stream as input and writes the frames into JPEG images. However, some of the output images are missing, and I'm not sure what's causing this issue. The input video which used in udp stream is clear and high-quality video and it is 1fps, H264 (High Profile) video. We are using ubuntu 20.04 on Virtual Box, video resolution is 1920x1080 (full HD). Since it is a 1fps video so total output frames or images is equals to video duration in secs. But in output images we are getting less no. of images. It is also not consistent with each run of code. Sometimes it misses 3 frames, sometimes 5 frames or sometimes 8 frames also. Also, there is no packet loss because the server and consumer are on same system.
1st code is a server pipeline which creates udp stream from input video.
GstElement *pipeline = gst_parse_launch(g_strdup_printf("filesrc location=%s ! qtdemux name=d d. ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink name=sink host=224.1.1.1 port=5000 auto-multicast=true", video_path), NULL );

then 2nd pipeline consumes this stream and write frames into jpeg images.
const gchar *pipeline_str ="udpsrc multicast-group=224.1.1.1 auto-multicast=true port=5000 caps = \"application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=96\" ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,format=BGR, pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1 ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! appsink name=sink sync=false";


Well, UDP transmission is by definition unreliable..

Could you make sure you are starting the consumer pipeline first and make sure it's running before starting the producer?

Thanks for your suggestion. I am already following it. I am starting consumer pipeline first and then server, but I continue have the missing frames issue.
